# Passing array into a Global Procedure

Tags: procedure, maya, mel

So I need to pass an array into a `global procedure`, but as usual I have to redefine it. I know this is a bit of a noobie question, but can array be passed into as procedure? If not, could it be made global and inserted into a procedure.

```
$selectedFace = `ls -selection` ;

global proc crTestScripts($selectedFace) {
    print ("OMG aren't lists of things awesome?!" + $selectedFace) ;
}
```

or

```
$selectedFace = `ls -selection` ;
global array? $selectedFace ;

global proc crTestScripts() {
    global array? $selectedFace ;
    print ("OMG aren't lists of things awesome?!" + $selectedFace) ;
}
```

I'm passing in this string and I still get this error:

`Error: Wrong number of arguments on call to applyCurrentType`

Here is a sample of the code:

```
string $selectedFace[] = `ls -sl` ;  

global proc applyCurrentType (string $selectedFace[]) {
    print("Apply Current Type button clicked\n") ;
    global int $applyCurrentType ;
    $applyCurrentType = 1 ;
    select -cl ;
    select $selectedFace ;
    crTestScripts ;
}
```

Comment: Tad late in the piece I know, but the error you're getting is probably due to how you're invoking your applyCurrentType() function.. if you can scratch that down we can probably help more? (the call should look like: `applyCurrentType($selectedFace)` methinks)

Answer (score 0):

I used `proc createControllers(string $name[], int $position)` in an auto rig script which is taking an array. I stay away from using the terms global when using mel since maya is picky and just use the rehash function whenever I make changes to my script;

```
proc buildRig()
{
    string $rootNode[]=`ls -sl`;
    createControllers($rootNode, 0);    
} 

proc createControllers(string $name[], int $position)
```

Worked for me. In the `proc createControllers` my `$name` array is equal to my `$rootNode` array.

Hope this Helps, good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the help! I thought I was going crazy, I mean of course an array can pass into a procedure! However it still isn't working for me.

I'm passing int this string and I still get this error:
Error: Wrong number of arguments on call to applyCurrentType

here is a sample of the code: 
  
string $selectedFace[] = `ls -sl`;   
global proc applyCurrentType (string $selectedFace[]){
 print("Apply Current Type button clicked\n");
 global int $applyCurrentType;
 $applyCurrentType = 1;
 select -cl;
 select $selectedFace;
 crTestScripts;
}

Answer (score 0):

my previous answer was wrong.

so to pass array into proc u need redefine it as global variable,
`string $selectedFace[];` will become
`global string $selectedFace[];`
inside procedure. e.g.:

```
string $selectedFace[] = filterExpand("-sm", 34, `ls-selection`);

global proc crTestScripts(){

    global string $selectedFace[];
    print $selectedFace;
}
```

`crTestScripts();`
`// result: body_skinPrx_finalSkin.f[103]`

*filterExpand gives two benefits, it flattens array `ls -fl`, and u can use multiple filters `-sm 34 -sm 31`*

or, i think best way... *(i don't like global vars)*
simply use normal syntax of variable declaration for args in round brackets:

> global proc proc_name( *args_here ){ somecode; return; }

*args:

> string $str, string $ls_str[], float $scaleX, float $scale[];.. vector $vec etc.

```
global proc hide_items(string $items[]){
    hide $items;
}
```

using previous list result `$selectedFace`:

`hide_items($selectedFace);`

oops... i forgot maya can't hide faces xD